# I need to know how to get the views from another layout xml file

Tags: kotlin-android-extensions

Is it possible to get the views from another layout using viewBinding?
or is there another way to get them?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentFirstBinding>(LayoutInflater.from(requireContext()), R.layout.fragment_first, null, false)
```